# SSH outside the local network

Tags: 14.04, ssh, openssh, port-forwarding

I have Ubuntu 14.04 LTS installed on a Toshiba Satellite L655.

I've recently installed an SSH server on the machine and it works fine when connecting to it using `192.168.1.3` but when I try that using the public IP address it returns `Connection times out`.

I've already port forwarded:

[image]

`sudo iptables -L` output :

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

`/etc/ssh/sshd_config` : http://paste.ubuntu.com/10739399/

`sudo netstat -pln | fgrep ssh` output :

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      952/sshd
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      952/sshd
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     12292    1247/ssh-agent      /tmp/ssh-DUPQCwc5sHdL/agent.1246
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     56778    3637/ssh-agent      /tmp/ssh-ouP0FhPELKCM/agent.3636
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     13982    1869/gnome-keyring- /run/user/1000/keyring-f2DhKb/ssh
```

Comment: What command are you using while `ssh`-ing using the public IP? Also are you using public IP while `ssh`-ing from inside the LAN?

Comment: make sure your gateway in ubuntu is  directed to the gateway the port forwarded has.. and also make sure to test using a different network, ie using another internet connection ie mobile connection/dongle

Comment: Is the server listening on all addresses?

Comment: @DavidFoerster i did some portforwrding for windows ftp server and vnc server on the same router before and it worked.

Comment: @heemayl I don't know what you mean !

Comment: @Aravinda i tried to connect from my mobile. Same results

Comment: @KenSharp I don't know

Comment: @AliAlmoullim Run `sudo netstat -pln | fgrep ssh` to find out.

Comment: @DavidFoerster Updated the post

Comment: @KenSharp Updated the post

Comment: @AliAlmoullim Try removing `#` from `#ListenAddress 0.0.0.0` in your `sshd_config` and restarting the daemon.

Comment: @DavidFoerster Well why don't we find out instead of guessing?

Comment: There are no firewall rules and `sshd_config` has no source address rules. I'm out of ideas.

Comment: @DavidFoerster @KenSharp i removed the `#`. it didn't changes anything

Comment: @AliAlmoullim Is there anything in the syslog?

Comment: @DavidFoerster I've just tried to connect to a VNC server to make sure it's a SSH problem and it didn't connect either so it's not from the SSH server. Now what :)

Comment: I'd say it's a router/NAT issue and unrelated to Ubuntu. Speaking from personal experience, consumer grade plastic routers seem to go wonky sometimes and it helps to reboot them.

Comment: Can you add the IP address to a DMZ for testing? Remember that it will fully expose the system to the Internet so you won't want to keep it open for long.

Comment: @KenSharp i tried that it didnt work, the problem is obviously with the router, maybe portforwarding is disabled or something, i dont know. i tried searching about the router model, got nothing!